# Color picker for entire screen

Tags: software-recommendation

Is there any application that provides a color picker for the screen?

For example: after starting the application the mouse is transformed into a color picker.
Clicking anywhere on the screen it will detect the pixel color.

Comment: I wrote one for windows, but have not thought about it for Ubuntu, may give it a try some tine.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel see the answer to the following http://askubuntu.com/questions/163783/tool-to-easily-select-a-pixel-on-screen-and-get-color-and-absolute-coordinates?rq=1

Comment: @SimplySimon Not a duplicate. I would say the q&a you linked to is a subset of this question. The OP's requirements and use case in the other Q&A are way more specific than with this one.

Comment: John, could you please comment on the duplicate status of this question? I personally think it is a dupe, but some people think it's not. Does the master question answer your question?

Comment: @Seth, I think it's not a duplicate. I agree with Glutanimate.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### Newer alternatives to gcolor2

---

**Overview**

gcolor2 is good but hasn't been updated in quite a while. There are two more recent alternatives out there, [gcolor3](https://github.com/Unia/gcolor3) and [pychrom](http://xyne.archlinux.ca/projects/pychrom/).

**gcolor3**

The first one is a GTK3 port of gcolor2. There are no differences in the features it comes with as far as I can tell:

[image]

**pychrom**

pychrom on the other hand has a few additional goodies:

- CMYK and terminal color support
- systray indicator
- zoom function

A couple of screenshots of pychrom in action:

[image]

[image]

**Installation**

The downside to these more recent color pickers is that they aren't available from the official repositories or any other repos for that matter.

`gcolor3` you will have to compile manually. Please follow the instructions on the [project page](https://github.com/Unia/gcolor3) to do so.

`pychrom` is a python application and can be executed without having to be compiled first. The [source archive](http://xyne.archlinux.ca/projects/pychrom/src/) comes with two files, `pychrom` and `pychrom.desktop`. To install the application simply copy `pychrom` to your `PATH` (e.g. `~/bin` or `/usr/local/bin`) and move the `.desktop` file either to `~/.local/share/applications` (user-bound installation) or `/usr/share/applications` (system-wide installation).

Comment: We need a PPA for gcolor3

Answer (score 22):

Yes there is. It's called [gcolor2[image: Install gcolo2]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gcolor2/) and it's very simple to use it. You can install it from [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal) using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install gcolor2
```

[image: gcolor2]

Comment: Ubuntu 18: `Unable to locate package gcolor2`

Answer (score 10):

I would suggest **gpick** as it's simple and to the point:

```
sudo apt-get install gpick
```

### Usage

Unfortunately this app has a very non-intuitive UI, so here's help on how to use it (or at least how I use it):

1. **Right-click** on the center hexagon (the red one in the screenshot).
2. Move pointer around the screen. A zoom-view (similar to the lower-left corner of Gpick) will follow your mouse to help you pick the exact pixel you want.
3. Press <kbd>Space bar</kbd> to add the color to the selected slot in the palette. Slot 1 is selected at first by default.
4. You can drag a color from a slot an drop it into where you need it, e.g. Gimp, Inkscape, or simple read its #rrggbb-value.

### Hints

1. After adding a color, the next slot will automatically be selected so you can press <kbd>Space bar</kbd> successively to add to the ring buffer of slots.
2. Instead of right-clicking the center-hexagon, you can instead click the pipette in the lower-right corner or left-click-AND-drag.  I personally find right-clicking the center easier.

[image]

Comment: Nice one too! Upvoted :)

Comment: +1 for explaining how it works - I had given up on using gpick to identify a color outside its own window.  lousy UI, but relevant to this question now....

Comment: Still doesn't work, most likely because of Wayland. At least gcolor3 reports this, gpick simply doesn't work with no message at all. Nevertheless thank you for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

I like "Pick". It's very easy to use, eye-friendly and to the point:
https://snapcraft.io/pick-colour-picker