# xrandr gives black background

Tags: multiple-monitors, xrandr

I use Ubuntu 12.04 on a Toshiba Portege R600.  Normally I have a flat green background (the middle choice of the custom set under wallpapers in the right-mouse-click GUI).

When I plug in a VGA monitor for two-screen usage the background on that and on the laptop screen go black.  They remain black after I unplug the monitor and give the command:

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --auto --output VGA1 --off
```

Is there a trick to maintain the green blackground, at least on the laptop screen, or at least regain it automatically on the laptop screen?

Comment: Per OP, resolved by upgrading: "This bug went away when I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on a new Toshiba Z930."

Answer (score 1):

An workaround will be to use the following command:

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --auto --output VGA1 --off && gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background primary-color "#73D216"
```

This will set again your background color to #73D216 (green).

Comment: Thanks but no go: DISPLAY=:0: Command not found.  Sorry, should have added I use Gnome Classic.

Comment: @RobRutten Are you sure that you copy it correctly? Dont't use any space before or after `=` sign.

Comment: alias vga-off 'xrandr --output LVDS1 --auto --output VGA1 --off && DISPLAY=:0 GSETTINGS_BACKEND=dconf gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background primary-color "#73D216"'

Comment: Or is it my use of tcsh?  Sorry, I am not too unix-knowledgeable...

Comment: @RobRutten Oh... tcsh. Ok, don't use these variables `DISPLAY=:0 GSETTINGS_BACKEND=dconf`. See if it is working with `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background primary-color "#73D216"` only.

Comment: Yes, that's it!  Many thanks!  Is there a palette or such to choose a color specifying such code number?

Comment: @RobRutten Yes, you can use [gcolor2](http://askubuntu.com/a/351470/147044). If this answered your question, you may [mark this answer as accepted](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers), by clicking the green check mark next to it. That will indicate that your problem is solved.

Comment: Hold!  I found a nifty color code finder at http://www.colorpicker.com/     Question closed- Thanks!

Comment: @RobRutten Well, are many useful tools in this sense.

Comment: Sorry!  I was too quick.  The gsettings background color definition only works after I have manually reset the background with the GUI. After switching off or unplugging he second VGA monitor the background stays black also when  apply your command. he gestetings command

Comment: Then run again `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background primary-color "#73D216"` only.

Comment: I tried that.  The background stays black.  If I reset it with the GUI then after that the command does work.

Comment: @RobRutten Maybe you have a bug. That command will not work if you have an image set as background.

Comment: @ Radu Radeanu  I don't use an image but the central lightgreen "custom" flat background in the Appearance GUI.  I tried instead with an (ugly) wallpaper from upper choice in the GUI: xrandr then works properly, giving that background on both screens and keeping it after unplugging or my vga-off.  With the flat choice and your command above the green flashes momentarily into view when I unplug and then the background goes black and stays black, the command won't work afterwards either - until I revive the GUI choice and then it does work.  Some real bug I suspect.  Thanks anyhow!

Comment: @RobRutten Sound like a bug. See [How do I report a bug?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 0):

This bug went away when I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on a new Toshiba Z930.